# React-Router: How to retrieve the current route's parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to retrieve the current route's parent? I need it in order to be able to navigate "up" in my app.

Answer (score 1):

In child component's render -

```
var currentPath = this.props.location.pathname,
parentPath = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
return (<Link to={parentPath}>Up</Link>...);
```

Comment: That goes on the assumption that you nest routes for each `/`.  Parameterized routes often have multiple depths in a single container.

Comment: Thanks for adding that piece. You are right about the assumptions.